# Qt. Работоспособность асинхронного API в отдельном потоке

Tags: c++, qt, асинхронность, qthread, modbus

Не уверен, что правильно сформировал заголовок, но постараюсь объяснить в основной части.
Разрабатывается приложение при помощи Qt и возникла необходимость заставить некоторый код работать постоянно, не прерывая основную программу. Конкретнее: в программе реализуется modbus, отправка и прием выполняются с момента запуска и до момента закрытия, при этом прочий функционал не должен из-за этого страдать. Сразу возникла идея вынести это всё в отдельный поток, но есть некоторые сомнения. В документации сказано, что библиотека modbus имеет асинхронный API. На данный момент предполагаю реализацию так: создаю отдельный класс, в конструкторе которого инициализируется объект класса QModbusRtuSerialMaster, реализуется первоначальное подключение к порту. Затем, в `mainwindow.cpp` происходит что-то подобное:

```
PlcModbus *plc = new PlcModbus;
QThread *thread_modbus = new QThread;
plc->moveToThread(thread_modbus);
connect(thread_modbus, &QThread::started, plc, &PlcModbus::startModbus);
thread_modbus->start();
```

В отдельном потоке начинает крутиться процесс непрерывной приемо-передачи.
Так вот, в чем вопрос, может ли влиять на результат выполнения тот факт, что я засунул в поток что-то, что исполняется асинхронно? Есть ли вероятность, что это вызовет конфликт и функциональность будет нарушена?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51975005/multiple-threads-with-libmodbus

Comment: Написанное там актуально и для QModbusClient?

Comment: При использовании асинхронного API отпадает необходимость создавать поток и наоборот.

Comment: ....The number of requests executed in parallel is dependent on the protocol.